# MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID is distinct by song

Tags: android, mediastore

```
String[] projections = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
```

Shouldn't MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID by the id field for the song, and MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID be the id field for the album?  What I want to see is a common ID field for all songs on an album.  What is the correct field to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY is unique per album

Comment: Thank you, wish this was better documented by Google.